# Reopen application with last selected fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sorry for my little question but I am searching it now for hours and I am gonna be crazy if I could not find a answer.

I am making an android studio app with one MainActivity and multiple fragments, but what I want is that when users select the fragment and they come back the app saves the selected fragment and the apps reopens in that fragment, hopefully I will get an answer or any help. Please help me out of this! ( sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about this is by using `SharedPreferences` to keep track of the last visible `Fragment`.

For instance, in your `Activity`'s `onStop()` or `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method, put the current `Fragment`'s ID or tag in `SharedPreferences`. In your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, get the ID or tag preference of the `Fragment` that you put in `SharedPreferences`. If the value is not null, compare the value to your `Fragment` IDs or tags using a `switch-case`, instantiate the `Fragment`, and add and commit the `Fragment` to a `FragmentTransaction`. Otherwise, add and commit your default initial `Fragment`.

If you want to do perform the same logic with `Activities`, you could create a launch/splash `Activity` that contains similar logic to get the last opened `Activity`.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.login.LaunchActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

In the `onCreate()` method of your `LaunchActivity` class:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
String activityTag = editor.getString(getString(R.string.last_viewed_activity_tag), null);

// If the user is not launching the app for the first time, launch the last opened Activity; otherwise, launch the default initial Activity.
Class initialActivityClass;
switch (activityTag) {
    case "CoolActivity":
        initialActivityClass = CoolActivity.class;
        break;
    case "WowActivity":
        initialActivityClass = WowActivity.class;
        break;
    default:
        initialActivityClass = MainActivity.class;
        break;
}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, initialActivityClass);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: You can do the same process in the `SplashScreen Activity` & take user to fragment depending on `SharedPreference` value.

Comment: Could you please help me al little bit more with the coding system? Cause I am new to android studio and don't know too muh how to do what you say. I already did a research to codes on google but didn't found anything of kind what you said.

Comment: And sorry for my question I said fragments but it can be activities too I know how to switch inside activities with buttons but don't know how to save the last used activity to reload on next application start.

Comment: @TheGrafWolf01 I encourage reading up on `SharedPreferences` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and `FragmentTransaction`s [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I'll update my answer to include a solution for `Activities`.